# could anyone tell me about reverse linklist with diagram?

Tags: c

Diagram and program code in c is necessary.

Comment: It might be necessary for you, but it's not necessary for us.

Comment: hello dear plz tell me about singly reverse link list.i have seen this link it is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ReverseLinkedList.aspx

It's also on Google.